# What practically computable homotopy and/or (co)homology theories are known for finite (di)graphs, metric spaces, etc?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, big-list

Of late I have taken to applying Dowker homology and the path homology theory of Grigor'yan et al. like a hammer to various relations and/or digraphs that have looked like nails. At the same time, I have ideas about applying magnitude (a la Leinster and Meckes) to at least one real-world problem and can't help noticing magnitude homology of graphs.

Generally, I deal with finite/discrete structures a lot and so would like to see what hammers are out there so as to keep my eyes peeled for any matching nails. That is,

> I am hoping to get an exhaustive picture of what topological theories
> have been devised for "nice" finite objects, with an eye towards
> investigating any that have (or at least admit) practically computable
> algorithms.

Because of the algorithmic focus, I am not sure if I should include, e.g., any Khovanov or Kontsevich stuff, which never seemed very accessible and/or applicable to my naive eye, and I certainly don't understand it.

Google Scholar could answer this in principle, but an hour or so has convinced me that this is a worse idea than asking here.

To avoid degeneracy, I will omit the algebraic topology of finite topological spaces a la McCord. My first stab (which I'm fairly confident would omit something that I've already forgotten, let alone never heard of) is:

- Abstract simplicial complexes (included only for the sake of completeness)

  - simplicial (co)homology
  - discrete Morse theory
- Posets

  - (co)homology of the associated abstract simplicial complex
- Relations (and/or bipartite graphs)

  - Dowker homology = simplicial homology of an associated abstract simplicial complex

    - (eminently computable)
- Metric spaces

  - [homology theory of Barcelo et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3915)
  - [magnitude homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.00802)

    - (note that this generalizes Hepworth-Willerton graph homology, so tenatively not including that under "graphs")
- Graphs

  - degenerately, simplicial stuff
- Digraphs

  - [path (co)homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2834) and [homotopy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0234) theories of Grigor'yan et al.

    - ([homotopy theory of Barcelo et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403146) apparently equivalent to this)
    - (homology computable at reasonable scale, but with exponential complexity in dimension)

For some of these (e.g., magnitude homology) I don't yet have a real idea of the computational practicality, and I would be especially interested in any observations in this vein and/or pointers to code.

**I would encourage answerers to update this list as well as answering below.**